# Console.log() has a value but when I used it with map function it became undefined [ReactJS]

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm very new to react.

can you help me, please

I have spent a lot of time to research this error. but I found nothing to solve my problem.

I use `console.log()` it returns an array.

but the next line, I used it with `.map()` function `on line 30`

it throws an error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

this is my ***render()*** function

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {console.log("errrrrrrrrrrrrr",this.state.allowedRoutes)}
        {this.state.allowedRoutes.map(route => (
          <Route
            exact
            path={route.url}
            component={allRoutes[route.component]}
            key={route.url}
          />
        ))}
        {this.state.redirectRoutes.map(url => (
          <Redirect to={url} />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

it logged the `{console.log("errrrrrrrrrrrrr",this.state.allowedRoutes)}`'s value.

but It cannot use `map()` function.

this is what my browser logged.

`errrrrrrrrrrrrr (8) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]`

this is an error my browser:

[image: an error]

Comment: do `{this.state.allowedRoutes && this.state.allowedRoutes.map....}` instead.

Comment: What is the exact error you get?

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @VLAZ https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8pkp.png it is above.

Comment: can you paste entire `render()` method

Comment: _"How do I ask a good question?"_ -> _"**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question**. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text."_

Comment: `console.log(typeof this.state.allowedRoutes)` and `console.log(Array.isArray(this.state.allowedRoutes))` and let us know the results.

Comment: @tex it logged ***object*** and ***true***

Comment: Always when you render this component the state `allowedRoutes` is an array?

Comment: nitpick: is missing `key` prop on the second map

Answer (score 0):

as error implies, `this.state.allowedRoutes` is undefined, either after logging the value or on subsequent renders.  you should also post your code too.
But for a workarround you can check not to be `undefined` with `this.state.allowedRouter && this.state.allowedRoutes.map()`

As a side note, apparently you are updating your state in render method which is also not correct.

Comment: Why do you think that him is updating the state in render method?

Comment: Because he's got an error in his console stating ``Cannot update during an existing state transition``

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that at some point you're updating your state and by mistake deleting `allowedRoutes`. If you set your state without [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) it first, all previous data will be removed, examples:

```
// WRONG - STATE BECOMES { allowedRoutes: myArray }
this.setState({
  allowedRoutes: myArray
});

// RIGHT - STATE BECOMES { all previous properties plus allowedRoutes: myArray }
this.setState({
  ...this.state,
  allowedRoutes: myArray
});
```

Also be sure to be initializing allowedRoutes as an empty array if you want to use `map` without checking the value first (`map` is an array method).

If you're using classes:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {allowedRoutes: []};
}
```

If you're using hooks:

```
const [allowedRoutes, setAllowedRoutes] = useState([]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your picture shows that the exception was thrown inside `.map`:

```
this.state.allowedRoutes.map(
  // the exception was thrown here
  ...
)
```

Please notice at this line, you can see `allRoutes` is not defined in the current scope.

```
component={allRoutes[route.component]}
```