# react throws error for undefined object before ternary can check if object is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, multer

I am having the dreaded cannot read status of undefined. I am using React for the front end, and mongodb, express, and nodejs for the backend.

I am using functional components. The "bag" props has bag.disccollection and bag.image.data.

bag.disccollection is an array of objects and bag.image.data contains an array of bson image data that is stored on my mongodb database. Fetching this data from the mongodb from postman allows me to view the image so I think the image is working.

As you can see below, I use a ternary operator for displaying bag.discollection, because I will get the undefined/null error if I dont check that "bag" exists. However I use the same logic for bag.image.data and I am getting the error shown below.
edit: Github repo https://github.com/2stash/discgolf.git

```
const DiscBag = ({
  getBag,
  auth: { user },
  bag: { bag, loading, editdisc },
}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    getBag();
  }, [getBag]);

  return loading && bag === null ? (
    <Spinner />
  ) : (
    <Fragment>
      <h1 className='large text-primary'>Dashboard</h1>
      <p className='lead'>
        <i className='fas fa-user'></i> Welcome {user && user.name}
      </p>
      {!editdisc ? <AddDisc /> : <EditDisc />}

      {bag !== null ? (
        <DisplayDiscs discList={bag.disccollection} />
      ) : (
        <DisplayEmptyBag />
      )}
      
      {bag !== null && bag.image !== null ? <Image data={bag.image.data}/> : <p>Hi</p>}
 
    </Fragment>
  );
```

Here is the error message I am currently getting.

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'statusText' of undefined
(anonymous function)
C:/Users/Daniel/projects/discgolf/client/src/actions/bag.js:24
  21 |   } catch (err) {
  22 |     dispatch({
  23 |       type: BAG_ERROR,
> 24 |       payload: { msg: err.response.statusText, status: err.response.status },
  25 |     });
  26 |   }
  27 | }
```

Here is my Image component. I am working on converting the bson back to an image to display. If I comment out "let imageStr..." , the console.log will work and display the data.

```
const Image = ({ data }) => {
  
  const imageData = data
  let imageStr = arrayBufferToBase64(imageData)
  console.log(imageData)

  const arrayBufferToBase64 = (buffer) => {
    let binary = '';
    let bytes = [].slice.call(new Uint8Array(buffer));

    bytes.forEach(b => binary += String.fromCharCode(b));

    return window.btoa(binary);
  }
  return <p>Hi</p>
    
};

Image.propTypes = {
  data: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
};

export default Image;
```

Any thoughts on how to debug. I am really confused because I am using a ternary operator and it is working find for my other data, and the data seems to be arriving correctly. Also I don't know why my redux action would be throwing an error.  (and if anyone has a better solution for image handling for a mern stack let me know)

edit to add redux action code: also link to github for stable version without this image feature included

```
import axios from "axios";
import { setAlert } from "./alert";

import { 
  GET_BAG,
  BAG_ERROR,
  DELETE_DISC,
  SET_DISC,
  UPDATE_DISC,
} from "./types";

// Get current users bag
export const getBag = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get("/api/bag/me");
    // console.log(res.data)
    dispatch({
      type: GET_BAG,
      payload: res.data,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({
      type: BAG_ERROR,
      payload: { msg: err.response.statusText, status: err.response.status },
    });
  }
}
```

Update: I went into the redux actions file for bag.js and removed the error payload messages and I get the following message

```
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'arrayBufferToBase64' before initialization
Image
C:/Users/Daniel/projects/discgolf/client/src/components/discbag-copy/Image.js:10
   7 | const Image = ({ data }) => {
   8 |   
   9 |   const imageData = data
> 10 |  arrayBufferToBase64(imageData)
  11 |   console.log(imageData)
  12 | 
  13 |   const arrayBufferToBase64 = (buffer) => {
```

Comment: can you share your projects/discgolf/client/src/actions/bag.js file ? error is coming from that component

Comment: Instead bag !== null && bag.image !== null ? <Image  you could try: bag?.image? ? <Image... etc

Comment: I added the redux action code. You are right the error is from there. But I can't imagine why because the bag.disccollection is essentially the same check and that works.

Comment: @pmiranda I tried the code below, and it will load the <Image /> component, and not the text in the <p> tag, which indicates both ternary's are true, but I still get the same error.
      {bag ? (bag.image ? <Image data={bag.image.data}/> : null) : <p>Image component not loaded</p>}

Answer (score 0):

You have checked bag.image for a null value. You should also check it for undefined.
Instead of having a check for a specific value (null), you can check for falsy value.

For example,

!!bag && !!bag.image

If bag variable is null, !!bag will return false. If it has a truthy value !!bag will return true.
With this check, if bag and bag.image are null or undefined, both will be taken care of.

Comment: Yes I have tried checking the bag and the bag.image for truthy/falsy. That was an answer I found on other posts like this link here. But it did not work. Also, the data is console.logged and shown that it is there. Verified also by opening up the database, as well as getting the data back through postman test. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59591000/console-log-has-a-value-but-when-i-used-it-with-map-function-it-became-undefin)

Comment: Could you put then the new code that you have been tested? In a codesandbox or jsfiddle, it doesn't matter if has compile errors, jus to see the whole component code